# d3.js Trying to create a grid and don't know how to access certain elements or bind to columns

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have two questions that are related.  I am trying to make a rectangular grid based on my csv dataset, where each rectangle represents a data point.  Eventually, I went to set the opacity of each cell based on the min/max scale for that column.

My first attempt was to create rows per d elements. I found some code to do this:

```
     for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++ ) {

          // create each set of rows
          var rows = svg.selectAll('rect' + ' .row-' + (n + 1))
            .data(d3.range(headers.length))
            .enter().append('rect')
            .attr({
              class: function(d, i) {
                return 'col-' + (i + 1);
              },
              id: function(d, i) {
                return 's-' + (n + 1) + (i + 1);
              },
              width: square,
              height: square,
              x: function(d, i) {
                return i * square;
              },
              y: n * square,
              fill: 'red'
            })
```

I'm not fully understanding how this works.  It creates n rows based on the number of rows in my csv.  But now I can't move forward because I don't know how to set the opacity.  I want to create an anonymous function on the fill attribute, but I don't know how to access what column of the CSV I'm in.  If I access i, it would be what row I'm in, and if I access d then it is undefined.

My next thought was to instead, just each column to set of rectangles. Is there a way I can access just that column.  So:

```
var column1 = data[Column1];  
var column1Scale = .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["Column1"]}),
                    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Column1"]})])

var column1rects = svg.select("body").data(column1).enter().append("rect")...
```

I can then set the x to be the same for each rectangle and use an anonymous function with y, and then call the scale on the opacity.

But, I don't know how to access just that column, or do I just reference in by name like I did in the scale function?  And lastly, am I going about building a grid all wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks like an interesting question that might be useful to others, but without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, it is hard to look into. Have a look here for how to add one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also sometimes still struggle with the [D3 data join](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data). Some may find Mike Bostock's [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) page useful.

What helps me is to imagine a D3 selection of DOM elements as an array which can be associated with an array of data entries. This association happens whenever you say `.data(yourData)` on a D3 selection.

After that, you can let D3 take care of creating "missing" DOM elements via the `.enter()` selection. That means for all the elements that exist in `yourData` but not yet in the DOM, you can do something like `.append(yourNewElement)`.

In your case, the data set is 2-dimensional: The CSV is basically an array of rows and each row is an array of data entries. That means you need two places where you join the respective arrays to some DOM elements:

1. Each data row can be associated with a group of grid cells
2. and each one of these groups can be associated with the elements of its row.

Based on your code, I came up with the following example which lets you address each grid cell individually:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
var square = 20,
    data = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ];

var rows = svg.selectAll('g') // Select all 'g' (SVG group) elements
        .data(data),          // and associate each one with a data row.
    newRows = rows.enter();   // Create the "enter selection", i.e. all
                              // data rows that don't exist yet as 'g' elements.

newRows.append('g') // Create 'g' elements for each row
    .attr('transform', function(row_d, row_i) {
        // The new group is translated vertically dependent on the row_i
        return 'translate(0,' + (row_i * square) + ')'
    });

// Now that all rows are created, let's create the rectangles in each row:
rows.each(function(row_d, row_i) {
    var row = d3.select(this),        // Select 'this', which refers to the 'g' 
                                      // element of the current row.
        cells = row.selectAll('rect') // Select all 'rect' elements in this row
            .data(row_d),             // and associate each one with a data entry.
        newCells = cells.enter();     // Create the "enter selection", i.e. all
                                      // data entries that don't exist yet as 'rect' elements.

    // Create 'rect' elements for each new entry:
    newCells.append('rect').attr({
        y: 0,                   // The enclosing 'g' elements take care of the y axis,
        x: function(cell_d, cell_i) { // so we only need to set x dependent on cell_i, 
            return cell_i * square;   // which is the index of the cell within the row.
        },
        width: square,
        height: square,
        fill: function(cell_d, cell_i) {  
            // here we can do anything with the current cell data cell_d
            return d3.rgb(cell_d*25,cell_d*25,cell_d*25);
            // or with cell_i, which is effectively the column index:
            //return d3.rgb(cell_i*100,cell_i*100,cell_i*100);              
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply.  I'm still reading it over and over to make sure I get it.  I feel like I actually understand the data append, but I couldn't figure out with a 2d array.